# Levenshtein distance between two columns of two different dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, levenshtein-distance

Let's say i have two dataframes

Dataframe 1:

| ID1 | NAME1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | JUANA |
| 2 | LUCAS |
| 3 | PEDRO |
| 4 | MATIAS |

Dataframe 2:

| ID2 | NAME2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | JUAN |
| 2 | JUANA |
| 3 | JUANITA |
| 4 | MATIAS |
| 5 | MATIA |
| 6 | MATIAS |
| 7 | MATIAZ |

Each one don't have the same numbers of rows. I would like to create a third dataframe that compares each value of the first dataframe with the second.

Dataframe 3:

| ID1 | NAME1 | NAME 2 | Levenshtein |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | JUANA | JUANA | 0 |
| 1 | JUANA | JUAN | 1 |
| 1 | JUANA | JUANITA | 3 |
| 2 | LUCAS |  | 5 |
| 3 | PEDRO |  | 5 |
| 4 | MATIAS | MATIAS | 0 |
| 4 | MATIAS | MATIA | 1 |
| 4 | MATIAS | MATIAZ | 1 |

Is there a way to accomplish that?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you have rows where Name2 is blank?

Comment: Why isn't JUANA compared to MATIAS?